# VBA Code: How would you partial out a user input and then select a sheet from there

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble finding a way that would look at a user input if the user input is = 10-1 then it brings up the worksheet 10-1. If the user inputs is = 10 then if brings another input box that would then ask the user to enter 1,2 and if the user enters 1 it will bring up 10-1 sheet if he enters 2 then it will bring up 10-2 sheet. Another example is if the user enters 100 it will bring an input saying "enter a load" from 1,2,3 if the user inputs a 3 it will bring up 100-3 sheet. If the user input 4 then it will return a message box saying sheet does not exist.

Code:

```
Private Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
    SheetExists = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name = name Then SheetExists = True: Exit Function
    Next
    
End Function

Private Function ConfirmEndSub()
    ConfirmEndSub = MsgBox("Do you really want to QUIT", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
    If ConfirmEndSub = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Thank You Goodbye"
    End If
        
End Function

Sub InputValidation()
    Dim str As String
    Dim inp As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim reply As Long

    str = MsgBox("Do you want to select a dataset (Yes) or a Graph (No)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If str = vbYes Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            reply = ConfirmEndSub
            If reply = vbYes Then Exit Sub
        ElseIf SheetExists(inp) Then
            Worksheets(inp).Activate
        Else
            MsgBox "This load and test cannot be found"
        End If
    ElseIf str = vbNo Then
        inp = InputBox("Please enter a load value (10 or a load and trial (10-1)")
        If StrPtr(inp) = 0 Then
            reply = ConfirmEndSub
            If reply = vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Hoping to get my program to work

Comment: I know you need to use a Instr but I don't know how that will work

Comment: Why not have your userform have 2 boxes, each requiring input?  You can monkey around with an inputbox and data validation, or ask for exactly what you want.

Comment: Or just show them a list of the sheets?